# Partitioning geospatial data in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, geospatial, partitioning

I am having problems in creating partitions for a table having geospatial data (i.e shape column). I have a table building which has geospatial data and I want to create a partition based on statename.

I created a buildingpartiton table as follows

```
 SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
 SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=non-strict;

 create table buildingpartition (OBJECTID string,
> RILUNIQUEID string,
> RILFEATURECODE string,
> BLDGNO string,
> BLDGNAME string,
> BLDGTYPE string,
> BLDGSUBTYPE string,
> BLDGCLASS string,
> BLDGROAD string,
> BLDGSUBROAD string,
> SUBLOCALITY string,
> BLDGSIZE string,
> TAG string,
> PINCODE string,
> NUMBEROFFLATS string,
> NUMBEROFSHOPS string,
> BLDG_TYPE string,
> CABLEOPERATORNAME string,
> AREA_1 string,
> LBU2 string,
> SHAPE binary)
> Partitioned by (STATENAME string)
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
> STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.UnenclosedJsonInputFormat'
>   OUTPUTFORMAT'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

Then i tried to insert data into this table from an existing building table. this buidling table consists of 40 million records.

```
 > Insert into table buildingpartition parition (statename) select * from building;
```

I am getting the main cause of the error as

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSLimitException$PathComponentTooLongException): The maximum path component name limit of statename=00 00 00 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 40 a0 a2 83 ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 70 a7 13 4d 7b 61 43 41 40 c9 31 72 b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 in directory /apps/hive/warehouse/proddb.db/buildingpartition/.hive-staging_hive_2016-12-15_10-58-15_294_7141760028369054723-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10002 is exceeded: limit=255 length=408

Can anyone help me out with this problem? I have attached the full error trace below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"objectid":null,"riluniqueid":"KOL_A_LO0000_0597215","rilfeaturecode":"LO0000","bldgno":"null","bldgname":"null","bldgtype":"1","bldgsubtype":"Unclassified","bldgclass":"Building","bldgroad":"PURANO BAZAR BRIDGE","bldgsubroad":"P K VISHWAS ROAD","sublocality":"Milan Garh Colony","statename":"West Bengal","bldgsize":"G + 0","tag":"null","pincode":"700119","numberofflats":"0","numberofshops":"0","bldg_type":"Others","cableoperatorname":"null","area_1":"0.0","lbu2":"null","shape":�T
                                                                                                          �"A�m�{aCA��%��"A����aCA�T
                                                                                                                                    �"AIXz�aCA@����"A����aCA��%��"Ap�M{aCA@�1r�"A�m�{aCA�T
                  �"AIXz�aCA}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"objectid":null,"riluniqueid":"KOL_A_LO0000_0597215","rilfeaturecode":"LO0000","bldgno":"null","bldgname":"null","bldgtype":"1","bldgsubtype":"Unclassified","bldgclass":"Building","bldgroad":"PURANO BAZAR BRIDGE","bldgsubroad":"P K VISHWAS ROAD","sublocality":"Milan Garh Colony","statename":"West Bengal","bldgsize":"G + 0","tag":"null","pincode":"700119","numberofflats":"0","numberofshops":"0","bldg_type":"Others","cableoperatorname":"null","area_1":"0.0","lbu2":"null","shape":�T
                                                                                  �"A�m�{aCA��%��"A����aCA�T
                                                                                                            �"AIXz�aCA@����"A����aCA��%��"Ap�M{aCA@�1r�"A�m�{aCA�T
                                                                                                                                                                  �"AIXz�aCA}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
        ... 8 more
*Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSLimitException$PathComponentTooLongException): The maximum path component name limit of statename=00 00 00 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 40 a0 a2 83 ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 70 a7 13 4d 7b 61 43 41 40 c9 31 72 b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 in directory /apps/hive/warehouse/proddb.db/buildingpartition/.hive-staging_hive_2016-12-15_10-58-15_294_7141760028369054723-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10002 is exceeded: limit=255 length=408*
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.verifyMaxComponentLength(FSDirectory.java:949)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.addLastINode(FSDirectory.java:1014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirMkdirOp.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createSingleDirectory(FSDirMkdirOp.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createChildrenDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createAncestorDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2615)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2377)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:708)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:577)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createNewPaths(FileSinkOperator.java:859)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.getDynOutPaths(FileSinkOperator.java:966)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:552)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSLimitException$PathComponentTooLongException): The maximum path component name limit of statename=00 00 00 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 40 a0 a2 83 ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 70 a7 13 4d 7b 61 43 41 40 c9 31 72 b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 in directory /apps/hive/warehouse/proddb.db/buildingpartition/.hive-staging_hive_2016-12-15_10-58-15_294_7141760028369054723-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10002 is exceeded: limit=255 length=408
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.verifyMaxComponentLength(FSDirectory.java:949)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.addLastINode(FSDirectory.java:1014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirMkdirOp.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createSingleDirectory(FSDirMkdirOp.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createChildrenDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createAncestorDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2615)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2377)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketForFileIdx(FileSinkOperator.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:566)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSLimitException$PathComponentTooLongException): The maximum path component name limit of statename=00 00 00 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 40 a0 a2 83 ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 70 a7 13 4d 7b 61 43 41 40 c9 31 72 b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 in directory /apps/hive/warehouse/proddb.db/buildingpartition/.hive-staging_hive_2016-12-15_10-58-15_294_7141760028369054723-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10002 is exceeded: limit=255 length=408
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.verifyMaxComponentLength(FSDirectory.java:949)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.addLastINode(FSDirectory.java:1014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirMkdirOp.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createSingleDirectory(FSDirMkdirOp.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createChildrenDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createAncestorDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2615)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2377)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:298)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:256)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1716)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:802)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:246)
        ... 20 more
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask**

Answer (score 1):

It says right there in error that partition directory name is exceeding naming convention limit -

The maximum path component name limit of **statename=00 00 00 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41 40 a0 a2 83 ed 17 22 41 a0 82 cd c2 80 61 43 41 c0 84 25 eb ed 17 22 41 70 a7 13 4d 7b 61 43 41 40 c9 31 72 b0 17 22 41 f0 6d 9e 04 7b 61 43 41 00 83 54 0b b0 17 22 41 18 49 58 7a 80 61 43 41** in directory /apps/hive/warehouse/proddb.db/buildingpartition/.hive-staging_hive_2016-12-15_10-58-15_294_7141760028369054723-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10002 is exceeded: **limit=255 length=408** at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.verifyMaxComponentLength(FSDirectory.java:949)

Your table is getting partitioned on SHAPE column instead of STATENAME column because you are inserting using select * statement.

Column on which the table should be partitioned must be mentioned as last column in select query.

right way to do it is -

```
from building 
insert overwrite table buildingpartition partition(statename)
select col1,col2..... , statename  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added "hive-hcatalog-core.jar" ? Some distribution require this jar for JSON SerDe.[see Apache Hive JSON SerDe instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-JSON)

Other possibility is - error in SerDE that you are using.